# Use Python code to show a list of users that have Owner permissions to my Azure subscription

Tags: python, azure, sdk

I am trying to find all the users in my subscription that have the role of Owner. I have to use python to do this and Microsoft doesn't seem to have any working options for this.

I've ran several options with the Azure SDK for Python class at [azure.mgmt.authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-authorization/azure.mgmt.authorization.authorizationmanagementclient?source=recommendations&view=azure-python) to try to return an appropriate result but nothing is working. Here are 2 options I've tried so far:

```
from azure.mgmt.authorization import AuthorizationManagementClient

authorization_client = AuthorizationManagementClient(credentials, '<your subscription guid>')

roles = authorization_client.role_assignments.list()
for role in roles:
    print(role)
```

This returns all of the role assignments in the subscription but only displays the RoleAssignmentID. It does not show the username or role definition name (owner).

```
from azure.mgmt.authorization import AuthorizationManagementClient

authorization_client = AuthorizationManagementClient(credentials, '<your subscription guid>')

roles = authorization_client.role_definitions.list(
        scope=subscription_id, filter='roleName eq \'Owner\''
    )
for role in roles:
    print(role)
```

This returns details on the Owner role but doesn't show who has this role in my subscription. Any help would be great!

Comment: Instead of working with python, it will be easy to use a direct PowerShell command that exists with Microsoft Azure, to get the required information. If it works with you, I can provide you the answer as per your question.

Answer (score 0):

*To list all the users in a subscription that have owner role:*

This Azure PowerShell command `get-azroleassignment` provides all the owner roles. It worked as below:

```
get-azroleassignment -RoleDefinitionId "xxxxxxxx" -Scope "/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>"
```

[image]

*To display* `name & signin name`(mail) use `select` *operator*:

```
 get-azroleassignment -RoleDefinitionId "xxxxxxxx" -Scope "/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>" | select Displayname, signinName
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you are trying to list out using `azure python sdk`, below given code will work given by @colbydh.

***I modified and created a below script:***

```py
from  azure.mgmt.authorization  import  AuthorizationManagementClient
from  azure.identity  import  AzureCliCredential
credentials = AzureCliCredential()
authorizationClient = AuthorizationManagementClient(credentials, subscriptionID='<subscriptionID>')
def  list_of_owners(client):
results = []
owners_list = []
subscription_scope = '/subscriptions/<subscriptionID>'
owner_role = '8e3af657-a8ff-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'  
roles = client.role_assignments.list_for_scope(
scope = subscriptionScope,
filter = 'atScope()'
)
for  role  in  roles:
role_name_id = role.name
role_assignment_details client.role_assignments.get(
scope = subscriptionScope,
role_assignment_name = role_name_id
)
roleid = role_assignment_details.properties.role_definition_id
if  owner_role  in  role_ids:
owner_role_list = roleid.count(owner_role)
print(owner_role_list)
```

[image]

Refer [Pyquestions article](https://pyquestions.com/how-to-get-list-of-users-who-are-having-owner-access-for-a-azure-subscription-using-python).